# Using overprint inside wrapfigure for beamer

Tags: beamer, wrapfigure

I'm trying to change my figures while keeping the texts the same. From some research, I found the `overprint` environment which should allow me to achieve what I want. Now, I want to put that inside a `wrapfigure` environment, too. Something along the line of:

```
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{General concept}
    \begin{wrapfigure}[9]{L}[10pt]{0.32\textwidth}
      \begin{overprint}
        \onslide<1>\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{gmls-concept-0.png}
        \onslide<2>\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{gmls-concept-1.png}
        \onslide<3>\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{gmls-concept-2.png}
        \onslide<4>\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{gmls-concept-3.png}
      \end{overprint}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    % texts here.
\end{frame}
```

The output I have is the figure overflowing the slides and now contained inside the defined region for `wrapfigure`. Is there a way to work around it?

Comment: Please add a sketch of the expected output to your question. Does your slide really contein that much text, that you need `wrapfig`? Wouldn't a simple `column`-based approach be sufficient to place images and text onto a beamer frame?